# Bad request when accessing API endpoint programatically in python

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I'm trying to get data from an API endpoint from [Adidas](https://shop.adidas.co.in/gateway/catalog/api/page/ADIDAS_IN/kids-products/get?_=1483101382714).
When I access this url from browser, I am able to get the response.
But when I access it using 'wget', I get an error :

> ERROR 400: Bad Request

When i access it using python, I get an error :

> {"code":1,"type":"error","message":"Invalid locale format: *"}

I am unable to drill down the reason behind this. I have checked request header information also but i couldn't reach to a conclusion.
I'm missing something that must be really obvious to others so if you know, please tell me.
My python code is a simple request using requests module :

```
import requests
url = 'https://shop.adidas.co.in/gateway/catalog/api/page/ADIDAS_IN/kids-products/get?_=1483101382714'
try : 
    request = requests.get(url)
    print request.url
    print request.text
except Exception as exp : 
    print exp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, pay attention to the headers.

`'Accept-Language'` is expected by the server.

```
import requests
url = 'https://shop.adidas.co.in/gateway/catalog/api/page/ADIDAS_IN/kids-products/get?_=1483101382714'
try : 
    headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla 5.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en'
    }

    request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print request.url
    print request.text
except Exception as exp : 
    print exp
```

Comment: I knew the **locale** has something to do with localisation but still didn't worked at that time. Anyways, its working now. Thanks for your help mate :-)